# ReactJS: Apollo graphql client. Cache not updating locally

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo

So I have a simple todo app, that stores and gets data from the database.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/

I use Refetching Queries from Apollo Client as the data in my frontend needs to be updated when a list is added, updated or deleted. Please refer to this link, I follow the exact steps they mentioned and It works as expected, I can see my updated values in Apollo In memory Cache.

But my issue here is that the react frontend app does not update the list, When I pass the data as a dependency array, It works and data is updating, but goes in an infinite loop and lags very bad. I am pretty sure I am fetching the data the right way and using the useEffect properly, and I don't think I need to add the data as a dependency array but I am not sure let me know if I am wrong.

Am I missing any steps here?
I fetch the data from useEffect, the In memory cache is updated, I am re fetching the queries as they said in the apollo client and I can see that the cache is updated in the dev tools, but why isn't my frontend updating?

Comment: Please provide some code showing how you are fetching the data

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple rule in React-> to update anything on-screen re-render is needed. so, check if that is an issue.
You can share your React code also to get to know more about what is issue.